# Infragistics iggrid : add custom filter after rendering

Tags: jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

In the process of making an Excel-style filtering on an iggrid, I would like to hide some custom filter conditions after displaying the grid.

I already saw that: http://infragistics.com/community/forums/t/97384.aspx, but is there any way to do so without parsing all the DOM? Isn't there any way to intervene on the filter conditions ?

Especially since I'm going to add many filter conditions, I would rather have it in data than in display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer there !

http://infragistics.com/community/forums/p/108265/509836.aspx

Simply kill and reboot the grid, adding a few custom conditions in the process.